# FireFox 29 often loses connection

Tags: firefox

It started happening few days ago. In my work I have two browsers open - FireFox and Chrome.

It happens several times a day that FireFox suddenly cannot load any page, Facebook chats and notifications stop refreshing and nothing new can be opened. Meanwhile everything still works in Chrome! I have to close FireFox (and have to click twice on the cross to make it quit!) and restart to make it work again.

I use Ubuntu 12.10, BUT exactly the same problem happened on my home desktop pc with Windows 8.1 and different ISP, so it must be a Mozilla's problem.

Comment: So this is happening at work and at home?

Comment: It must be Mozilla's problem? Or one of the plugins you're using (if you're using any)? To rule it out, run it in safe mode or uninstall/update all plugins. The fact it happens on home and work is strange... Unless you're sharing details between them or using the same plugins

Comment: Today I woke my work laptop from suspend and again FireFox could not not anything and had to be restarted (by clicking twice on cross...). These are my extensions and plugins
FireGestures 1.8.6
LastPass 3.1.1
Xmarks 4.3.1

DivX Web PLayer 1.4.0.233
LastPass 3.0.17
QuickTime Plug-in 7.6.6
Shockwave Flash 11.2.202.359
VLC Multimedia Plug-in 10

Comment: why can't we use line breaks in comments? :(

Comment: here it is again. I checked the web console and this is what was there
http://pastebin.com/wsYdpJXY